# What are the different international mathematics competitions that are held?

Tags: big-list, contest-math

Apart from the IMO which is for the younger students, I am looking for competitions which are maybe for undergraduates or graduate students.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find all related information at the below link:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematics_competitions

Undergraduate competitions which I know are:

- [Miklos Schweitzer (Hungary)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikl%C3%B3s_Schweitzer_Competition): Some of the problems of the competition are available [here](http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~mmaroti/schweitzer/).
- [Putnam(USA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lowell_Putnam_Mathematical_Competition): The Putnam problem archive. See this [link](http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnamindex.shtml).
- [Vojtech-Jarnik](http://vjimc.osu.cz/)
- [International Mathematics Competition For University Students](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mathematics_Competition_for_University_Students). The competition page is [here.](http://www.imc-math.org/)
- [Nordic Mathematical Contest](http://cc.oulu.fi/~phasto/competition/)
- [International Scientific Olympiad on Mathematics for Undergraduate University Students (ISOM)](http://olympiad.sanjesh.org/en/index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The Consortium For Mathematics and its Applications sponsors contests one of which is international in the are of Mathematical Modeling:  http://www.comap.com/undergraduate/contests/